# I am trying to use optional chaining in JS and it showing error

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

Why is my JS snippet throwing an error on `console.log`?

```js
var person = {
    name: 'John',
    pet: {
        name: 'Trixi',
    }
};

var petName = person.pet?.name;
console.log(petName);
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: Because you're running it on a browser or other environment that does not support optional chaining? Only Chrome 80 supports it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

Comment: Yes I am using this in Google Chrome

Comment: Version 80+? When I run your code in Chrome **79** I get the error. When I run it in Chrome **80** I do not.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I updated chrome to the latest version and now it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is currently supported on Chrome v80 or more, Firefox v74, and other browser's newest versions. More details: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

However, you can still enable it on the older browser by enabling the **Experimental JavaScript** config on the browser.

For example in Chrome, to do that, do access **chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony** in the URL, and then enable.